# why can't I inject socket.io using a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, google-chrome, socket.io

I have a really basic socket.io application that listens on the server side for a button click on an html page.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body><button id="asdf">click</buton></body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('connect',function(){ 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#asdf').click(function(){
        socket.emit('0.1');
    });
});
});
```

This part works. What I'd like to do is put this functionality into a chrome extension so that I can have my node app respond to events in the DOM. Right now, I have a background page that injects a script when the extension icon is clicked.

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: 'script.js'
    });
});
```

script.js:

```
console.log('test');
```

So this works too, but when I copy and paste the socket.io.js code into the script.js file, nothing is logged to the console, which I assume means that the script isn't working. Why doesn't this work, and is there a better way to integrate socket.io.js into a browser extension?

Comment: Can you show us the actual `script.js` file that isn't working?

Comment: Its too long, I basically just copied and pasted the code here https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js  into script.js.

Comment: I got this error from the "inspect views" console for background.js:
 Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL
    at chrome-extension://fflijpiahimgehhbbmcafgkpikiclmep/background.js:9:15extensions::sendRequest:82 handleResponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I basically ended up connecting to the socket through a background page, and sending messages through that page from the content script, which worked out ok for my application.